# Закрытие вопросов с ответами на домашнее задание

Tags: обсуждение

В последнее время в очереди на закрытие очень часто появляются вопросы (в основном от новых участников), в которых публикуется задание или скриншот какого-либо задания, предполагающего выбор правильного ответа из числа приведенных. При этом в вопросе содержится также предполагаемый вариант правильного ответа.

Так вот, я не совсем понимаю, на каком основании мы можем голосовать за закрытие этого вопроса с формулировкой: [image: ж]

Ведь человек сделал в точности то, о чем мы ему говорили: выполнил задание и просит его проверить. Как же мы можем закрывать его вопрос, ссылаясь на нарушение наших условий?

Я могу представить себе чувства задающего вопрос. Предположим, он ранее уже размещал подобное домашнее задание, но мы закрыли его вопрос с формулировкой "...можем проверить уже выполненные вами". Человек разместил новый вопрос, на этот раз уже с выполненным заданием (а по условию задания было необходимо именно выбрать правильный ответ, а не делать объяснение этого выбора, т.е. формально задание полностью выполнено). И вот мы вновь закрываем его вопрос с той же самой формулировкой!

Также я могу понять чувства человека, голосующего за закрытие. Вполне очевидно, что автор вопроса не предпринял никаких особых усилий по поиску правильно ответа, возможно даже просто выбрал один из вариантов ответа наугад лишь для того, чтобы его вопрос начал соответствовать формальным требованиям сайта. И да, такой вопрос интуитивно хочется закрыть. Но ведь мы, получив право голосовать за закрытие вопроса, должны не забывать и об ответственности за принятые нами решения, и мы не можем закрывать вопрос на основании одних лишь наших чувств, тем более ссылаясь на нарушение, которого в этом вопросе формально нет!

Мне кажется, с этим надо что-то делать. Либо необходимо изменить формулировку причины закрытия вопроса, чтобы под нее можно было, не кривя душой, подвести указанные выше вопросы, либо четко сказать: такие вопросы мы не закрываем, формально они не нарушают правила сайта.
А как думаете вы?

Answer (score 1):

«Думать» и принимать решение приходится модератору. Все же не могут «закрывать вопрос на основании одних лишь наших чувств», такого права им не дано. Таковы нехитрые правила.

Стало быть, менять *формулировку причины закрытия вопроса* нет нужды: всякий знает вес и вред подсказки и  меру пользы работы ума, а всякий опытный ясно видит где уловка, а где — доля труда.

Comment: Любой пользователь с достаточной репутацией может проголосовать за закрытие вопроса, а 5 таких пользователей могут реально закрыть любой вопрос. И в идеале при принятии подобного решения должно быть как можно меньше субъективизма, а для этого нужны четкие критерии, не противоречащие здравому смыслу и букве правил.

Comment: Меньше субъективизма может дать только максимум голосующих. Тогда надо обеспечивать всем право голоса. А портрет вопроса с вложением домашнего задания, конечно, можно написать маслом, однако ж кого заставишь в него всматриваться, если под ногами земля будет гореть.

Comment: @IvanOlshansky согласен с Shampar. Опытный пользователь сразу увидит где труд, а где уловка.